# jquery delay and repeat function

Tags: jquery, delay, setinterval, repeat

I want to repeat an animation on a simple picture, I have done it easily with the setinterval function. But I also want to delay the repetition for 5 seconds after the page loading.

Now I have this :

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#arrow").fadeToggle(400);
}, 1000);
```

And I would like to delay the animation like that, but it doesn't work :

```
setTimeout(
     setInterval(function(){
        $("#arrow").fadeToggle(400);
     }, 1000);
, 5000);
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Try turning it into a function, then delaying on that.

```
function fader() {
    setInterval(function(){
       $("#arrow").fadeToggle(400);
    }, 1000);
}
setTimeout(fader, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the setTimeout is fine but you could have the fadeToggle function call itself when complete (recursion)

```
function arrowFadeToggle(){
  $("#arrow").fadeToggle(1000,arrowFadeToggle);
}

setTimeout(arrowFadeToggle,5000);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fmja7js8/)**

Answer (score 1):

Beware that the `setInterval` might eventually cause your animations to get out of sync. In particular the issues is that the `setInterval` will fire regardless of whether the animation has finished or not. In this case, this is not a such a big deal, but if your delay was smaller, this might become an issue.

A more robust way to do this, would be:

```
function animateFade() {
   $('#arrow').fadeToggle(400).delay(600).promise().done(animateFade);
}

// Put this in your document ready handler, handles your initial delay
setTimeout(animateFade, 5000);
```

The `animateFade` function will call itself only after the animation with the delay has finished. This guarantees that you will never have two of the functions running at the same time (and that your animation never gets out of sync).

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cnhdmj48/)

Answer (score 0):

With setInterval it delays by itselft for 1s (in your case). By the way that's how to use both:

```
setTimeout(function(){

setInterval(function () {
console.log("Hi There I'll wait 10 seconds to start first time")
                        }, 3000);

},7000)
```